# Django CSV Export - Foreingkey

Tags: django, csv, foreign-keys, export

Export to CSV is working properly... BUT the only thing is that the model fields which are defined via a ForeignKey are outputted as their PK... How can I solve this?

Below the code in my views.py :

```
def export_cashflow_csv(request):
 response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cashflow.csv"'

 writer = csv.writer(response)
 writer.writerow(['date', 'type', 'amount', 'fund', 'description'])

 cashflows = CashFlow.objects.all().values_list('date', 'type', 'amount', 'fund', 'description')
 for cashflow in cashflows:
    writer.writerow(cashflow)
 return response
```

the field fund is a Foreignkey to the model Fund.

many thanks all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `Fund` fields you want to export, e.g.

```
cashflows = CashFlow.objects.values_list(
    'date', 
    'type', 
    'amount', 
    'fund__name', 
    'fund__type', 
    'description')
```